# Ghost Cleanup settings

Tags: sql-server-2012, ghost-cleanup

I'm running a high transactional database (~175k transactions / Minute on average, 
almost 9M records per hour added and removed)

Up till recently this hasn't been too much of an issue as we've been at ~7.5M records added and removed but with the latest influxes of data the ghost cleanup doesn't appear to be able to keep up with cleaning up the unused space on tables / indexes.

A few days ago we reached 53 GB of 'Unused Space' across 16 tables (mostly 2 of them) so as a result started looking into the ghost cleanup process to find it runs once every 5 seconds and runs over 10 pages.

My current solution is that early morning I am running three threads of the following command:

```
DECLARE @2hours datetime = dateadd(hour,2,getutcdate())

WHILE getutcdate() < @2hours
BEGIN
    DBCC FORCEGHOSTCLEANUP ('DBNAME') WITH  NO_INFOMSGS
END
```

to catch up with the backlog from the night before (when most of our deletes take place)

I'm wondering if there's any way to change the default settings from 5 seconds and 10 pages to say every second or run over 20 pages, is there any way of doing that or should I continue just spinning up multiple cleanup procs to clear out the data, or if there's any other actions that can assist with this

Re-indexing runs on most effected indexs atleast once a week (most are every other day)

SQL Server 2012 Enterprise SP3_CU8 (upgrading to CU9 tomorrow) on AlwaysOn High Availabilty Cluster also with replication (distribution on a separate server)

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering if there's any way to change the default settings from 5 seconds and 10 pages to say every second or run over 20 pages

No there is none. Atleast I dont know as of now :-)

> if there's any other actions that can assist with this

[From Paul Randal's blog](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/turning-off-the-ghost-cleanup-task-for-a-performance-gain/) - One method people sometimes consider is to force ghost cleanup to clean everything by performing a table or index scan (thus queuing all the deleted records up for the ghost cleanup task).

```
select * from [your_problem_table] with (index = Index_that_has_large_Deletes)
```

Is there a possibility for you to **partition the table and purge the old partition instead of doing deletes** ? FYI .. SQL Server 2016 and up allows you to truncate individual partitions as well.

Also, you can *(TEST and implement)* - [disable ghost clean-up (trace flag 661)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/turning-off-the-ghost-cleanup-task-for-a-performance-gain/) and then `rebuild index WITH ONLINE = ON` option since you are using Enterprise edition.

If  you are using AlwaysON (with async) with replication, make sure to enable [Trace flag 1448](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability) - allows the replication log reader to move forward even if the asynchronous secondary replicas have not acknowledged the reception of a change.

Make sure to read [Deletes that Split Pages and Forwarded Ghosts](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2012/08/deletes-that-split-pages-and-forwarded-ghosts.html) from Paul White to see if your tables have triggers or LOB columns that would slow down.